# SNMP tick counter wrap around logic

Tags: monitoring, snmp, central-processing-unit

I'm trying to calculate CPU usage in percent over SNMP of a remote agent based on the `ssCpuRaw*` tick counters. As I understand it they are all of type `COUNTER(32 bit)` so tey'll wrap around to zero after they hit their `MAX` value.

The agent I'm monitoring is about 80% of the time idle, so the idle counter will wrap around first at some point in the future long before the others do. My question now is what happens with the other counters after the idle counter hits `MAX`? Is SNMP smart enough to reset the other `ssCpuRaw*` counters too? Otherwise the relation between those counter would be woefully misleading, rendering every attempt to calculate the percentage useless until all(!) the remaining counters wrapped around or am I completely off here?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? There are plugins that do this already.

Answer (score 0):

No, if it were to reset the other counters, you would lose the numbers accumulated between the last query and the wrap.

The appropriate method to query these counters is

- issue a GET request for `sysUptime.0` and the counter values in a single packet, so you get an atomic view
- use the `sysUptime.0` object to find out whether the agent has been reset.
- calculate difference to last query for each counter separately, correcting for wrap

Your query needs to be frequent enough that you do not miss two overflows in a row, which should be easy enough. The test for reset is used to filter out spikes that occur, e.g. if the counter appears to wrap from 3,000,000,000 to 0.

This does mean that you cannot interpret data gathered after one of the counters has already wrapped once.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I take the deltas anyway so there is indeed no wrapping problem unless the wrap happens in between the polls. The part with the `sysUptime` however I did not understand since when the agent is reboot all counters get reset anyway. So what do I need this object for exactly ... apart from giving me the uptime?

Comment: You can detect a wrap easily (counter decreases) and correct by adding `MAX+1` -- however if the counter was reset because the agent was reset, this would look like a wrap, so you don't correct if the `sysUptime.0` also decreased.